# Why am I getting a 403 error in YouTube Data API v3?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to use the `youtube-v3-api` for a school project. I keep getting the message, "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)."
How can I get past this?

Comment: You get passed the exceed quota you need to pay for an API subscription

Comment: @blurfus: Sorry, but what you're saying isn't necessarily true. The OP has several options at his disposal, from using cheaper API endpoints (instead of expensive ones, depending, of course, of his app functions), to applying for quota extension (which does not entail paying at all).

Comment: @dennis francis: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. Afterwards, [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64438445/edit), adding to it relevant missing information (without which the other SO users cannot come to your help).